# Recovering grub2 without LiveCD

Tags: grub2

Windows deleted my grub2 install so I need to reinstall it. All methods I read say "use your LiveCD and run chroot", I cannot use a LiveCD. I do not have my original LiveCD and I cannot download a new image because I'm on an unstable connection with max 100kb/s download so downloading a large file just isn't going to happen.

Is there anyway I can download just grub2 and install that?

Comment: Remember that if you torrent the .iso (.torrent files are available on the site), you won't have to worry about your unstable connection.

Comment: Ahh yes, I will use that as a last resort after I have tried the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes download `boot-repair` rescue disk. Half the size (350mb) but easy to use

Here is the link, http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/

Perform a `recommened repair`

Option 2:

Use super grub disk. A bit harder to work but very small size.

http://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/

This wiki will help you

http://www.supergrubdisk.org/wiki/Howto_Fix_Grub#Windows_Solution

Answer (score 1):

A favorite of mine to use is [Slitaz](http://www.slitaz.org/en/) linux, as it's only around 40mb, and then to chroot into my other install to fix as necessary.